# In android how do I view an outgoing request created by an HttpURLConnection for debugging?

Tags: android, http

The following code works but I am trying to insert the Json into the Http request body and I don't know if I am building the request properly. I would like to know how to print the request before I send it.

```
private class LoginAsync1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: ");
        String reply = sendPost("http://10.160.35.32:888/api/User/Login");

        Log.d(TAG, "reply: " + reply);

        return null;
    }
}


private String sendPost(String searchQuery)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "sendPost: ");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    OutputStreamWriter wr = null;
    InputStream is_response = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;

    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("LoginName", "bbbbb");
        jsonObject.put("Password", "bbbbb");
        jsonObject.put("LanguageCode", "en");

        String message = jsonObject.toString();


        URL url = new URL(searchQuery);



        if (url.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals("https"))
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "url.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals('https')");

            return "failure";
        }
        else
        {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        }

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(message.getBytes().length);

        con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


        wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(message);
        wr.flush();

        String req = con.getContent().toString();

        Log.d(TAG, "req");
        Log.d(TAG, req);

        con.connect();



        is_response = con.getInputStream();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is_response));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            builder.append(line);
            Log.d(TAG, "line: " + line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e);

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception ", e);

        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(wr != null)
            {
                wr.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "wr.close()");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "wr == null");
            }

            if(is_response != null)
            {
                is_response.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "is_response.close()");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "is_response == null");
            }

            if(reader != null)
            {
                reader.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "reader.close()");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "reader == null");
            }

            if(con != null)
            {
                con.disconnect();
                Log.d(TAG, "con disconnected");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "con == null");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not a direct answer to your question, but you can simplify your code a lot by just using OkHttp for your requests - http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Then, to get a proper logging mechanism you can just use okhttp-logging-interceptor - https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor.